# Get input accessory view's y position

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

Hello guys I was trying to get the y position of the input accessory view of a keyboard like this:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
     ipvFrame = textView.inputAccessoryView.frame;
}

-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
     NSLog(@"Input Accessory View:%f",ipvFrame.origin.y);   
}
```

However the NSLog is saying the ipvFrame y posit is 0! Anyone know why?

Comment: Have you performed alloc, init of ipvFrame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably *is* 0 in its superview’s coordinate space. Try converting its frame to the coordinate space of your current view controller’s view using `-[UIView` [`convertPoint:toView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint%3atoView%3a)`]` or one of the other methods like that one.